# Discord API node.js hover for tooltip

Tags: api, discord, discord.js, bots

I wanted to add a tooltip to my workinprogress bot, but I got this error.

/home/runner/simplebot/index.js:46
.setColor("#4287f5").setTitle("ToolTip Example").setDescription('Hover for tooltip': [(i)](${ message.url } 'Hey look! Its a tooltip!') ); message.channel.send(tooltipEmbed);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

This is my code

```
      {
  const tooltipEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("#4287f5").setTitle("ToolTip Example").setDescription('Hover for tooltip': [(i)](${ message.url } 'Hey look! Its a tooltip!') ); message.channel.send(tooltipEmbed);
  }
```

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks!

-Sam

Answer (score 0):

It's due to your `.setDescription`. If you want a description in your embed, you'll have to use `.setDescription('Whatever you want')` If you take a look to your description:

```
.setDescription('Hover for tooltip': [(i)](${ message.url } 'Hey look! Its a tooltip!')
```

You see that there isn't just one string, infact, there are two, with `[(i)](${ message.url }` in between.

You can take a look in the docs from [discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=setDescription).